# Prepopulating fields in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I created a Visualforce page for my child object `Risk__c`. My parent object is called `Contract__c`.

When I click on the `New Risk` custom button, the visualforce page is opened.

The problem is, that unlike using the standard "new" functionality of salesforce, the related `ContractId__c` is now not populated on my visualforce page.

I have no idea how to go about this.
Tia.

Answer (score 1):

Override the new button , and navigate to your custom VF , with url parameters.

```
/apex/VF?fieldId=value
```

You can get the field id if you inspect the html elements of Risk standard layout.

Below shows how to find a custom field element's html id....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the standard new-button and create your own new-button using url parameters to prepopulate your fields on the visualforce page. The button should be URL like

```
/apex/yourVfPage?id1=value&id2=value
```

You can use more than 2 Ids - just use as many as you need. Replace Id1 and id2 with your field id tags you want to populate.

In your case you can use a mergefield to transport the parent id field dynamically. It could look like:

```
/apex/yourVfPage?idOfYourContractIdField={!id}
```